# Use general rule as part of a specific target in Gnu Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am curious if it is possible to use a general rule as part of a more specific rule in Gnu Make. This is easier to explain with an example:

```
%.o:
        $(FC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<


some_file.o:
        DO SOMETHING EXTRA
        PASS ON TO GENERAL FOR %.o
```

That is, I want the target for `some_file.o` to first do something extra, and then do what is specified for `%.o`. Of course, I could just be redundant and write

```
some_file.o:
        DO SOMETHING EXTRA
        $(FC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

But that is not as convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra rule that does not create the file itself:

```
%.o:
    $(FC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

some_file.o: thing

thing:
    DO SOMETHING EXTRA BUT DON'T CREATE some_file.o
```

Note that if `thing` is not created, this will cause `some_file.o` to be built every time.

Comment: This answer does exactly what I want. The only missing thing is to specify `think` to be a `.PHONY` target. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible in any reasonable way.  The best you can do is put the command into a variable, then reuse the variable:

```
FCCOMMAND = $(FC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o :
        $(FCCOMMAND)

some_file.o:
        DO SOMETHING EXTRA
        $(FCCOMMAND)
```

Comment: I think you are right, in that there is no way to pass on from a specific rule to a more general rule. Although what I wanted to achieve can be done with @rmartinjak's answer with the use of more dependencies.